# How to use Flask-Security register view?

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

Has anyone used `Flask-Security` extension for authentication? How do I get register view to work?

http://packages.python.org/Flask-Security/customizing.html

I am referring to link above.

```
 @app.route('/register', methods=['GET'])
 def register():
     return render_template('security/register_user.html')
```

I don't want to extend the default class, I just want to wrap the default registration view in my site layout so I did this.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}upload{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

{% from "security/_macros.html" import render_field_with_errors, render_field %}
{% include "security/_messages.html" %}
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="{{ url_for_security('register') }}" method="POST" name="register_user_form">
{{ register_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
{{ render_field_with_errors(register_user_form.email) }}
{{ render_field_with_errors(register_user_form.password) }}
{% if register_user_form.password_confirm %}
   {{ render_field_with_errors(register_user_form.password_confirm) }}
{% endif %}
{{ render_field(register_user_form.submit) }}
</form>
{% include "security/_menu.html" %}

{% endblock %}
```

And I am getting the following error?

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError
BuildError: ('security.register', {}, None)
```

Answer (score 40):

You don't need to create the view.  A default one is included in Flask-Security.
You just need to enable it in your flask app config:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECURITY_REGISTERABLE'] = True
```

With this, the '/register' route should work.
There is another configuration value to change the URL if desired:

```
app.config['SECURITY_REGISTER_URL'] = '/create_account'
```

Other Flask-Security configuration information can be found here:
http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/configuration.html

Comment: This answer helped me to get the form working, but for the complete Flask and Python newbies like myself: You have to init the security first in your app. See here: http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html I was trying to enable the /register/ endpoint but it never worked because I have never inited my security instance.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. 

This has solved my problem, but I was being presented with a different error message. I'll leave it here in case it helps future Googlers - and hopefully saves the the time I've wasted trying to track this down...

    werkzeug.routing.BuildError: could not build URL for endpoint 'security.register' did you mean 'security.login' instead?

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @dcr is helpful, but I would like to clarify it a bit and make explicit some things which are only implied, both here and in the documentation.

Flask-Security comes with default views (also called routes). Many of them can be enabled using the `-ABLE` config variables, like so:

```
app.config["SECURITY_REGISTERABLE"] = True
```

You have a choice: either enable and use the default view, **or** leave it disabled and use your own instead. *When you enable a view, you cannot then override it.* When you think about it, this makes sense. Why enable the view if you're just planning to use your own implementation? How is flask supposed to know which route to use? And on the flip side: *if a view is disabled, its endpoint will not work.*

If you are using the default view, then you can create URLs to it using e.g. `url_for('security.register')` (or `url_for_security('register')` in the old style). Flask-Security will also look for a [template](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/customizing.html) in `security/TEMPLATE_NAME.html` and use it to display the form if it exists. This allows you to make visual changes and wrap the form in your UI as desired.

So, now it should be clear why Werkzeug is complaining. Try running `flask routes` on the command line, and look at the output. You'll see something like this:

```
(venv) ⋊> ~/flaskapp on master ⨯ flask routes
Endpoint                    Methods    Rule
--------------------------  ---------  ------------------------------------------
index                       GET        /
register                    GET        /register
security.login              GET, POST  /login
security.logout             GET        /logout
[...]
```

Notice that the `security.register` endpoint doesn't exist, because you haven't turned on `REGISTERABLE`. So `url_for('security.register')` will fail.

Your view doesn't do anything custom, it just displays the template. This is why @dcr says, correctly, that you don't need to create the view. Let Flask-Security do that for you by deleting your `/register` route entirely and turning on `REGISTERABLE`. Because you have properly named the `register_user.html` template, and placed it in `templates/security/`, Flask-Security will use it to display the page with the default form (or whatever [form](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/customizing.html#forms) you provided when the security object was `init`'ed).

However! If the code you have there is just a placeholder, and you need to manipulate the form or the page somehow before display or when the user clicks submit, then you are going to want your own view. In this case, you should *not* enable `REGISTERABLE`, but this also means that `security.register` won't be available for you to use in `url_for()`. Instead, you'll use just `'register'` (or `'{bp_name}.register'` if your registration code is in a Blueprint). Also, you don't need to name your page anything in particular then because you aren't relying on someone else's implementation of the view. You could put it loose in your templates folder and call it `register.html`. Whatever path you choose, you will need to pass that to `render_template()` in your view method.

Thanks to [@drahoja9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9930799/drahoja9) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50864650/1749551) who finally made this clear to me.

Answer (score -1):

I have not really used Flask-Security but the Builderror is referring to the fact that flask cannot bind the security.register view to a URL. security is the name of the blueprint. So may I suggest you try to call the view as follows. Instead of app.route, use security.route.

```
@security.route('/register', methods=['GET'])
def register():
    return render_template('security/register_user.html')
```

Comment: No luck, it gives me TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: This failed for me with an infinite recursion.