# Flask-Security override register view

Tags: python, flask, overriding, flask-security

Is there some convenient way to override register view in Flask-Security? I'm pretty happy with the built-in view for registration, but I need it to be accessible only after authentication and by certain roles.

I tried to override it like this (with `SECURITY_REGISTER_URL='/register/'`) but that just takes the built-in function and mine is completely ignored:

```
@app.route('/register/')
@login_required
@roles_required('superuser')
def register():
    """View function which handles a registration request."""
    ...
```

So the question is - do I have to write my own register view from peak and disable the Flask-Security registration?

I thought also about checking the user login/role in register_user.html template and possibly redirecting back to home page, but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to achieve this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several hours I finally managed to get it working. I forgot to specify methods, while registering the route `@app.route('/register/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`. If you disable the original Flask-Security's register view (`SECURITY_REGISTERABLE = False`), it works like a charm!

Also, when you want to override some view from Flask-Security, that can't be disabled so easily, like login, you have to do the same thing as mentioned above, but also register your view/blueprint first!

Comment: After way too much time fighting with Flask-Security on this, I finally found this answer and finally got user registration working in my project. Thank you! Strangely, my `'/register'` route used to work and then somehow Flask-Security's took over. Just disabling it was the right thing to do: I never wanted Flask-Security's view to run since I had to set up a custom form object and do extra work after registration. Of course, I then had to change my `url_for` calls.